# Showing All Forms On Same Monitor As Main Form

Tags: vb.net, multiple-monitors

In my application, I have an number of forms that pop up (modally) on top of the main form when certain buttons are clicked.

This works fine when my application is running on Monitor 1 as I preset the location of the form.  However, if the user moves the main form to Monitor 2 and clicks these buttons, all of the popup forms still show on Monitor 1.

I found this code to push a form onto a second Monitor:

```
Form2.Location=Screen.AllScreens(UBound(Screen.AllScreens)).Bounds.Location + New Point(100,100)
Form2.Show()
```

However, is there a way I can detect what Monitor my Main Form is located on, and then push any requested forms onto that same monitor?

I also work with 3 Monitors, so I need all my forms to show on the same monitor as the Main app.

Thanks

Comment: You could use the `Move` event and move all forms relative to the main form.

Comment: Ah thankyou, that sounds like a good plan.  Do you have an example of how to keep my forms relative to the main form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this way you would have to have a reference to the other forms, or use the `OpenForms` property on the `Application` namespace and iterate them.

```
Private Sub form_Move(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Move
  frm2.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X + 200, Me.Location.Y + 200)
  ' move others
End Sub
```